# Nested Fragment Implementation

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested

I have declared an activity with three fragments inside a viewpager.  Now I want to call another fragment from third fragment. Is there any way to implement this

Comment: what do you mean by calling a fragment?

Comment: Exactly, calling a fragment doesn't makes sense? do you want to attach one fragment within an another fragment?

Comment: @Ritesh  I want to replace the third fragment with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

In the third fragment,`getFragmentManager().findFragmentByXX()`